# DataSource not updating, only with LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a LINQ To SQL class, which is initialized before the constructor (the tables are added to it, it works):

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
```

Then I have a listbox:

```
listBox1.DataSource = dc.MyTable;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox1.ValueMember = "PersonID";
```

Then I want to add a new record:

```
MyTable mt = new MyTable();
mt.Name = "John Smith";
mt.PersonID = 30;
dc.MyTable.InsertOnSubmit(mt);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

I want to refresh the listbox's datasource, by doing:

```
listBox1.DataSource = dc.MyTable;
```

...but the new record doesn't show up.
However, if I update the datasource like this:

```
var q = from x in dc.MyTable select x;
listBox1.DataSource = q;
```

This works.

My only question is: why? I saw that some people set the DataSource to null, then back to the table, but that doesn't solve my problem.

(it's a winforms project)

---

**listBox1.DataSource = dc.MyTable.ToList()** seems to solve the problem, answered by Ehsan Sajjad in the comments.

Comment: Added an edit, it's a Winforms project

Comment: have you tried: ``listBox1.DataSource = dc.MyTable.ToList()`` ?

Comment: Thank you, Ehsan, it works!

Answer (score 0):

When you update your datasource by assigning *the exact same object*, the control will never know that something changed. If you don't want to implement MVVM, MVC or something similar, you could just clear the value:

```
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = dc.MyTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ToList()` **can** cause performace (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15027581/4550393) issues when having lots of items. Since you don't really need `ToList()` in this case the better solution would be to clear the list and to rebind it thereafter:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
listBox1.DataSource = dc.MyTable;
```